# XPath in RSelenium: Find by text

Tags: r, xpath, rselenium

**Questions**:

- How can I find the element 1468 by it's text?
- Why is is not working in the way that I tried it?

**My approach**:

For the below html code snippet,

[image: HTML-Code]

when I do

```
> t <- remDr$findElement('xpath', "//li[@data-iid = '1468']")
> t$getElementText()
```

I get

```
[[1]]
[1] "Handel"
```

However, when I now search for

```
> remDr$findElement('xpath', "//li[text() = 'Handel']")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**:

`remDr$findElement('xpath', "//li[. = 'Handel']")` solves it.

With `text()`, I don't get the bold text. RSelenium is misleading in this as it does not return the `text()` when I use `getElementText()`, it rather returns `.`.